# Crystal report detail section make duplicate each rows? Why

Tags: mysql, .net, crystal-reports

I have to make a report where report shows the data of items from quotation_detail table having master table quotation_m here is my binding

```
        MyCommand.CommandText = "select *  from Quotient_M m join Quotient_D q on m.q_id = q.q_id   , Company c where m.Q_id = 5"
        MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand
        myDA.Fill(myDS, "Quotient_M")
        myDA.Fill(myDS, "Quotient_D")
        myDA.Fill(myDS, "Customer")


        Dim cr As New CrystalReport3()
        cr.SetDataSource(myDS)
        Dim rpt1 As New Report_Quotation()
        rpt1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
        rpt1.Show()
```

**query return record of 2 ROWS**
and here how i am presenting report

[image: here is report alignment]

and here is out put

[image: rows double]

Question:

why report duplicating each records when their are 2 in database query return and report after duplicating as in image shows 4

Comment: o bhai edit k sath answer hi dy dyta

Comment: There can be many reasons... check your query for linkings to see any duplicate rows are generated.. if you don't have control on linking you can just check the option `Select Distinct Records` from database menu

Answer (score 0):

thank you for you help i am still posting answer for other

group the detail feilds and surpess detail section in designer grouping is against qd_id of quotation_d primary key here is image of correction

[image: correction]